# Bing Maps V8 GeoJson click event on pin

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have a page that is calling a service that returns GeoJson.
Similar to the following code:

```
var usgsEarthquakeUrl = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?minmagnitude=3&format=geojson';

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', function () {
    Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.readFromUrl(usgsEarthquakeUrl,
        function (shapes) {
            //Add the shape(s) to the map.
            map.entities.push(shapes);
            }, 'callback');
        });
```

I would like to be able to add a "click" or "mouseover" event handler so that I can add an infobox showing some information about the pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this:

- Loop through each shape returned by the readFromUrl function and add the required events to them.
- Create a layer for loading the data on and add the events to the layer. This is much more efficient and makes the data management process easier if you want to do more than simply display a single data set on the map.

Here is how you would add an event to each individual shape:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    zoom: 4
});

var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), { visible: false });
infobox.setMap(map);

var usgsEarthquakeUrl = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?minmagnitude=3&format=geojson';

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', function () {
    Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.readFromUrl(usgsEarthquakeUrl, function (shapes) {
        //Add click event to each shape.
        for(var i = 0, len=shapes.length; i < len; i++){
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(shapes[i], 'click', showInfobox);
        }

        //Add shapes to the map.
        map.entities.push(shapes);
    }, 'callback');
});

function showInfobox(e){
    var shape = e.target;
    var loc = e.location; //Default to the location of the mouse event to show the infobox.

    //If the shape is a pushpin, use it's location to display the infobox.
    if(shape instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin){
        loc = shape.getLocation();
    }

    //Display the infoboc
    infobox.setOptions({location: loc, title: shape.metadata.title, visible: true });
}
```

Here is how you would do this using a layer (**recommended**):

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    zoom: 4
});

var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), { visible: false });
infobox.setMap(map);

var dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
map.layers.insert(dataLayer);

//Add click event to the layer.
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(dataLayer, 'click', showInfobox);

var usgsEarthquakeUrl = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?minmagnitude=3&format=geojson';

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', function () {
    Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.readFromUrl(usgsEarthquakeUrl, function (shapes) {      
        //Add shapes to the layer.
        dataLayer.add(shapes);
    }, 'callback');
});

function showInfobox(e){
    var shape = e.target;
    var loc = e.location; //Default to the location of the mouse event to show the infobox.

    //If the shape is a pushpin, use it's location to display the infobox.
    if(shape instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin){
        loc = shape.getLocation();
    }

    //Display the infoboc
    infobox.setOptions({location: loc, title: shape.metadata.title, visible: true });
}
```

Here is a [live sample](http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#GeoJson%20Shape%20Events).

Comment: That is perfect. I will use your "recommended" code. Thanks so much.